# Browserwindow's "restore" event not triggered when restored from tray

Tags: electron

The BrowserWindow is hidden after I click close button, but neither "restore" event nor "show" event is triggered when it is restored again after I click the tray icon. I wonder what's the event that is triggered when BrowserWindow is restored by "win.restore()".

main.js:

```
const createWindow = () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  win.on('close', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    win.hide()
  })

  win.on('restore', function (event) {
    console.log('restore event') //not triggered 
  })

  win.on('show', function (event) {
    console.log('show event') //not triggered
  })
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    tray = new Tray('./icon.png')
    tray.on('click', () => {
        win.restore();
        win.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        });
    createWindow()
})
```

Comment: Finally as @midnight-coding points out, I use win.show() rather than win.restore() and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start off with, you must ensure the icon path you are pointing to when instantiating Electron's [`Tray`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/tray) is a valid path. If it is not a valid path then no icon will display and the left click functionality will not work.

Make sure your `win` and `tray` variables are declared and scoped correctly.

I have moved the creation of your `Tray` into its own function (IE: `createTray`), just like your `createWindow` function.

Lastly, you can also use [`win.show()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winshow) in place of both the [`win.restore()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winrestore) and [`win.setAlwaysOnTop(true)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winsetalwaysontopflag-level-relativelevel) methods if you like. `win.show()` will always restore and focus (show) your window.

> Minimising the window and left-clicking the tray icon will `restore` and `show` your window.
>
> Closing the window and left-clicking the tray icon will (only) `show` your window. Restore is not necessary as the window does not get minimised when closed.

`main.js` (main thread)

```js
const app = require('electron').app;
const BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const Tray = require('electron').Tray;

const path = require("path");

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;
let tray;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new BrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    window.on('restore', (event) => {
        console.log('restore event') // Triggered
    })

    window.on('show', (event) => {
        console.log('show event') // Triggered
    })

    window.on('close', (event) => {
        // Ensure you have another way for user to close app
        event.preventDefault();
        window.hide()
    })

    return window;
}

function createTray() {
    let tray = new Tray('icon.png');

    // Show the window on left-click.
    tray.on('click', () => {
        window.show();
    });

    return tray;
}

app.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
    tray = createTray();
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

There is no doubt that Electron can be finicky to setup. You need to get everything in the right order and within the right scope for it all to work.